# How do I keep materials when applying geometry nodes

Tags: modifiers, texture-baking, baking, procedural, geometry-nodes

I am fairly new to the Blender community and am struggling to achieve applying a geometry node set and keeping it's materials. I bought this modular building pack and am planning on expanding upon it by creating multiple new modules, but I need to "apply modifiers" in order to export so I can use these as assets in Unreal.

I think the issue is that the base mesh which is hosting the geometry nodes has one material, but I am hoping there is a way to keep all materials, as if I expand upon this file, there could potentially be hundreds.

Thanks in advanced!

b

[image: Before applying]

[image: After applying]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [3.0.0 alpha](https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/). This problem has been fixed

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Unfortunately when I open this project in 3.0.0a it is missing modules, and when i go into the node editor to adjust the sliders, it immediately crashes. I don't know if this is a separate question or this could be addressed here. Thanks!